# What are some cases of existing communities which started to migrate to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, community

I am interested about some cases of communities that tried and succeeded or failed to migrate to an existing SE platform (and joining the existing members).

I need few cases which are easier to analyse, meaning that there are some discussion threads available or some kind of public data available.

Comment: Done, increased ∞ times,  up to 29% :)

Comment: Must... refrain... from... asking... "Is this homework?"

Comment: Some would argue that Facebook app development support tried and failed. And continue to fail every day, measured solely on the quality of the questions that come through.

Comment: @MrLister No, is not homework, and even if it was, the question/answer are useful for others too.

Comment: Chiphacker.com ([electronics.se] ) and [onstartups.se] were SE 1.0 third-party owned sites that were migrated to SE 2.0.

Comment: Ubuntu has been around a while and started using http://askubuntu.com